# how to seperate column data and store in array in bash script, where the column seperator is <space> and number of space is different in each row?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, cat

Let l have a file that contain a data like this:

```
-ab-a--a-- 1 abcd   abcd        934M Nov  2 00:14 abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-02_1234567890.zip
-ab-a--a-- 1 abcd   abcd         45M Nov  2 01:39 abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-02_1234567890.zip
-ab-a--a-- 1 abcd   abcd        7.1G Nov 12 02:35 abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-12_1234567890.zip
-ab-a--a-- 1 abcd   abcd       1020M Nov  9 03:32 abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-09_1234567890.zip
-ab-a--a-- 1 abcd   abcd        1.1G Nov 12 04:32 abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-12_1234567890.zip
-ab-a--a-- 1 abcd   abcd       1010G Nov  7 05:35 abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-07_1234567890.zip
-ab-a--a-- 1 abcd   abcd        2.0G Nov 12 06:41 abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-12_1234567890.zip
```

So how to store the time and zip file name in array from this file? There is different number of space in some rows.

I have tried this code:

```
readarray -t time_array <<< "cut -d ' ' -f  9 filename)"
readarray -t zip_array  <<< "cut -d ' ' -f 10 filename)"
```

this code only works when there is equal number of < space > as a column separator
but in the file there is not same number of space as a column seperator

I want the the output as:

time array contains:

```
00:14 
01:39 
02:35 
03:32 
04:32 
05:35 
06:41
```

and

zip_array contains:

```
abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-02_1234567890.zip
abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-02_1234567890.zip
abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-12_1234567890.zip
abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-09_1234567890.zip
abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-12_1234567890.zip
abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-07_1234567890.zip
abc_de-123.456.xyz-2022-11-12_1234567890.zip
```

Comment: If you do not insist to have the data in array you can use `awk` where you can further manage the data

Comment: Is it the output of `ls -l` ? If so, don't parse `ls` output.

Comment: DO NOT USE ls' output for anything. ls is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing ls' output with code are broken. Globs are much more simple AND correct: ''for file in *.txt''. Read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Moreover, you have duplicate filenames

Comment: file permissions invalid -ab-a--a--